# R: Counting rows in a dataframe in which all values fall within individual ranges

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (A rows x K columns).  For each column, I get the 5th and 95th percentile value.  I want to know how many rows in the df have all K of their values within these K sets of 5th and 95th percentile values.

Example code below works, removing rows that do not fall within the bounds (1 and 9 here, but in practice will be percentiles), and then counting what remains.  But A will be 10K and K will be 40, and I am simulating this dataframe 10K times, so I am wondering if there is code that will run faster.

```
data <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(3,5,7,8,5), c(2,8,9,5,9), c(9,1,1,8,9), 
        c(3,5,6,7,5))
Lower_Bound <- rbind(1,1,1,1,1)
Upper_Bound <- rbind(9,9,9,9,9)

for (i in c(1:5)) {
    data <- data[data[,i] > Lower_Bound[i,],]
    data <- data[data[,i] < Upper_Bound[i,],]
}

N <- nrow(data)
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and what the problem with your current code is

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: For me it is not clear what you exactly aim to achieve. Please try to be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: In every loop, the first variable `data` is overwritten by the second variable `data` and within the loop, the variable `data` is overwritten on each step. At the end you have a logical vector for the last column less than the upper bound only!

Comment: Hello dcarlson, thank you for your thoughts.  What happens when I run this code is all the rows are removed from the df data that have a first column value < Lower_Bound or > Upper_Bound first row values; or that have a second column value < Lower_Bound or > Upper_Bound second row values; etc.  This is as I want.  I was wondering if there was a more efficient approach to this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP is only interested in the *number of rows* which fulfill the condition. So, there is no need to actually *remove* rows from`data` that do not fall within the bounds. It is sufficient to count the number of rows which do fall within the bounds.

This answer contains solutions for

- matrices
- data.frames
- and a *benchmark* which compares

  - OP's approach,
  - `apply()` with matrices and data.frames,
  - an approach using `purrr`'s `map()` and `reduce()` functions.

#### `apply()` with matrices

Let's start with the provided sample `data` and fixed `Lower_Bound` and `Upper_Bound`. Please, note that all three objects  are *matrices* created by `rbind()`. This is in contrast to the text of the question which refers to *a dataframe (A rows x K columns)*. Anyhow, we will provide solutions for both cases.

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) all(x > Lower_Bound & x < Upper_Bound))
```

returns a vector of type logical

> ```
> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> ```

The number of rows which fulfill the condition can be derived by

```
N <- sum(apply(data, 1, function(x) all(x > Lower_Bound & x < Upper_Bound)))
N
```

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

because `TRUE` is coerced to `1L` and `FALSE` to `0L`.

---

The next step is to also *compute the bounds* for each column as 5th and 95th percentile. For this, we have to create a new sample dataset `mat`, again as *matrix*

```
# create sample data
n_col <- 5
n_row <- 10
set.seed(42) # required for reproducible results
mat <- sapply(1:n_col, function(x) rnorm(n_row, mean = x))
mat
```

> ```
>            [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
>  [1,] 2.3709584  3.3048697 2.693361 4.455450 5.205999
>  [2,] 0.4353018  4.2866454 1.218692 4.704837 4.638943
>  [3,] 1.3631284  0.6111393 2.828083 5.035104 5.758163
>  [4,] 1.6328626  1.7212112 4.214675 3.391074 4.273295
>  [5,] 1.4042683  1.8666787 4.895193 4.504955 3.631719
>  [6,] 0.8938755  2.6359504 2.569531 2.282991 5.432818
>  [7,] 2.5115220  1.7157471 2.742731 3.215541 4.188607
>  [8,] 0.9053410 -0.6564554 1.236837 3.149092 6.444101
>  [9,] 3.0184237 -0.4404669 3.460097 1.585792 4.568554
> [10,] 0.9372859  3.3201133 2.360005 4.036123 5.655648
> ```

For demonstration, each column has a different mean.

```
# count number of rows
probs <- c(0.05, 0.95)
bounds <- apply(mat, 2, quantile, probs)
idx <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(x > bounds[1, ] & x < bounds[2, ]))
N <- sum(idx)
N
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT8fh.png) 5

If required, the subset of `mat` which fulfills the condition can be derived by

```
mat[idx, ]
```

> ```
>           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
> [1,] 2.3709584 3.304870 2.693361 4.455450 5.205999
> [2,] 1.6328626 1.721211 4.214675 3.391074 4.273295
> [3,] 0.8938755 2.635950 2.569531 2.282991 5.432818
> [4,] 2.5115220 1.715747 2.742731 3.215541 4.188607
> [5,] 0.9372859 3.320113 2.360005 4.036123 5.655648
> ```

The bounds are

```
bounds
```

> ```
>         [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
> 5%  0.641660 -0.5592606 1.226857 1.899532 3.882318
> 95% 2.790318  3.8517060 4.588960 4.886484 6.135429
> ```

#### `apply()` with data.frames

In case the dataset is a  data.frame we can use the same code, i.e.,

```
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
probs <- c(0.05, 0.95)
bounds <- apply(df, 2, quantile, probs)
idx <- apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x > bounds[1, ] & x < bounds[2, ]))
N <- sum(idx)
```

#### Benchmark

The OP is looking for code which is faster than OP's own approach because the OP wants to replicate the simulation 10000 times.

So, here is a benchmark which compares

- *OP1*: OP's own approach using matrices
- *OP2*: a slightly modified version of *OP1*
- *apply_mat*: the `apply()` function with matrices
- *apply_df*: the `apply()` function with data.frames
- *purrr*: using `map()`, `pmap()`, and `reduce()` from the purrr package

(Note that the list of methods is not exhaustive)

The benchmark is repeated for varying problem sizes, i.e., 5, 10, and 40 columns as well as 100, 1000, and 10000 rows. The largest problem size corresponds to the size of OP's simulations. As some codes modify the input dataset, *all* runs start with a fresh copy of the input data.

```
library(bench)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

bm <- press(
  n_col = c(5L, 10L, 40L)
  , n_row = 10L^(2:4)
  , {
    set.seed(42)
    mat0 <- sapply(1:n_col, function(x) rnorm(n_row, mean = x))
    df0 <- as.data.frame(mat0)
    mark(
      OP1 = {
        data <- data.table::copy(mat0)
        Lower_Bound <- as.matrix(apply(data, 2, quantile, probs = 0.05), ncol = 1L)
        Upper_Bound <- as.matrix(apply(data, 2, quantile, probs = 0.95), ncol = 1L)
        for (i in seq_len(ncol(data))) {
          data <- data[data[, i] > Lower_Bound[i, ], ]
          data <- data[data[, i] < Upper_Bound[i, ], ]
        }
        nrow(data)
      },
      OP2 = {
        data <- data.table::copy(mat0)
        Lower_Bound <- as.matrix(apply(data, 2, quantile, probs = 0.05), ncol = 1L)
        Upper_Bound <- as.matrix(apply(data, 2, quantile, probs = 0.95), ncol = 1L)
        for (i in seq_len(ncol(data))) {
          data <- data[data[, i] > Lower_Bound[i, ] & data[, i] < Upper_Bound[i, ], ]
        }
        nrow(data)
      },
      apply_mat = {
        mat <- data.table::copy(mat0)
        probs <- c(0.05, 0.95)
        bounds <- apply(mat, 2, quantile, probs)
        idx <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(x > bounds[1, ] & x < bounds[2, ]))
        sum(idx)
      },
      apply_df = {
        df <- data.table::copy(df0)
        probs <- c(0.05, 0.95)
        bounds <- apply(df, 2, quantile, probs)
        idx <- apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x > bounds[1, ] & x < bounds[2, ]))
        sum(idx)
      },
      purrr = {
        data.table::copy(df0) %>% 
          map2(map_dfc(., quantile, probs), ~ (.x > .y[1L] & .x < .y[2L])) %>% 
          pmap(all) %>% 
          reduce(`+`)
      }
    )
  }    
)

autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Note the logarithmic time scale

```
print(bm[, 1:11], n = Inf)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 45 x 11
>    expression n_col n_row      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
>    <bch:expr> <int> <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
>  1 OP1            5   100   1.46ms   1.93ms    493.     88.44KB     0      248     0      503ms
>  2 OP2            5   100   1.34ms   1.78ms    534.     71.56KB     0      267     0      500ms
>  3 apply_mat      5   100   1.16ms   1.42ms    621.     26.66KB     2.17   286     1      461ms
>  4 apply_df       5   100   1.41ms    1.8ms    526.     34.75KB     0      263     0      500ms
>  5 purrr          5   100   2.34ms    2.6ms    374.     17.86KB     0      187     0      500ms
>  6 OP1           10   100   2.42ms   2.78ms    344.    205.03KB     0      172     0      500ms
>  7 OP2           10   100   2.37ms   2.71ms    354.    153.38KB     2.07   171     1      484ms
>  8 apply_mat     10   100   1.76ms   2.12ms    457.     51.64KB     0      229     0      501ms
>  9 apply_df      10   100   2.31ms   2.63ms    367.     67.78KB     0      184     0      501ms
> 10 purrr         10   100   3.44ms    4.1ms    222.     34.89KB     2.09   106     1      477ms
> 11 OP1           40   100    9.4ms  10.57ms     92.9   955.41KB     0       47     0      506ms
> 12 OP2           40   100   9.18ms  10.08ms     96.8   638.92KB     0       49     0      506ms
> 13 apply_mat     40   100   5.44ms   6.46ms    146.    429.95KB     2.12    69     1      472ms
> 14 apply_df      40   100   6.12ms   6.75ms    141.    608.66KB     0       71     0      503ms
> 15 purrr         40   100  10.43ms   11.8ms     84.9   149.53KB     0       43     0      507ms
> 16 OP1            5  1000   1.75ms   1.94ms    478.    837.55KB     2.10   228     1      477ms
> 17 OP2            5  1000   1.69ms   1.94ms    487.    674.36KB     0      244     0      501ms
> 18 apply_mat      5  1000   4.84ms   5.62ms    176.    255.17KB     0       89     0      506ms
> 19 apply_df       5  1000   6.37ms   7.66ms    122.    333.58KB     0       62     0      506ms
> 20 purrr          5  1000   9.86ms  11.22ms     87.7   165.52KB     2.14    41     1      467ms
> 21 OP1           10  1000   3.35ms   3.91ms    253.      1.89MB     0      127     0      503ms
> 22 OP2           10  1000   3.33ms   3.72ms    256.      1.41MB     2.06   124     1      484ms
> 23 apply_mat     10  1000   5.86ms   6.93ms    142.    491.09KB     0       72     0      508ms
> 24 apply_df      10  1000   7.74ms  10.08ms     99.2   647.86KB     0       50     0      504ms
> 25 purrr         10  1000  14.55ms  15.44ms     62.5   323.17KB     2.23    28     1      448ms
> 26 OP1           40  1000   13.8ms  16.28ms     58.8     8.68MB     2.18    27     1      459ms
> 27 OP2           40  1000  13.29ms  14.72ms     67.9     5.84MB     0       34     0      501ms
> 28 apply_mat     40  1000  12.17ms  13.85ms     68.5      4.1MB     2.14    32     1      467ms
> 29 apply_df      40  1000  14.61ms  15.86ms     62.9     5.78MB     0       32     0      509ms
> 30 purrr         40  1000  41.85ms  43.66ms     22.7     1.25MB     0       12     0      529ms
> 31 OP1            5 10000   5.57ms   6.55ms    147.      8.15MB     2.07    71     1      482ms
> 32 OP2            5 10000   5.38ms   6.27ms    157.      6.55MB     2.06    76     1      485ms
> 33 apply_mat      5 10000  43.98ms   46.9ms     20.7     2.48MB     0       11     0      532ms
> 34 apply_df       5 10000  53.59ms  56.53ms     17.8     3.24MB     3.57     5     1      280ms
> 35 purrr          5 10000  86.32ms  88.83ms     11.1      1.6MB     0        6     0      540ms
> 36 OP1           10 10000  12.03ms  13.63ms     72.3    18.97MB     2.07    35     1      484ms
> 37 OP2           10 10000  11.66ms  12.97ms     76.5    14.07MB     4.25    36     2      471ms
> 38 apply_mat     10 10000  50.31ms  51.77ms     18.5     4.77MB     0       10     0      541ms
> 39 apply_df      10 10000  62.09ms  65.17ms     15.1      6.3MB     0        8     0      528ms
> 40 purrr         10 10000 125.82ms  128.3ms      7.35    3.13MB     2.45     3     1      408ms
> 41 OP1           40 10000  53.38ms  56.34ms     16.2    87.79MB     5.41     6     2      369ms
> 42 OP2           40 10000  46.24ms  47.43ms     20.3    58.82MB     2.25     9     1      444ms
> 43 apply_mat     40 10000  78.25ms  83.79ms     11.4    40.94MB     2.85     4     1      351ms
> 44 apply_df      40 10000  95.66ms  97.02ms     10.3    57.58MB     2.06     5     1      486ms
> 45 purrr         40 10000 361.26ms 373.23ms      2.68   12.31MB     0        2     0      746ms
> ```

#### Conclusions

To my surprise, OPs approach does perform quite well despite the repeated copy operations. In fact, for OP's problem size of 10000 rows and 40 columns the modified version *OP2* is nearly tow times faster than *apply_mat*.

A possible explanation (which needs to be verified, though) is that OPs approach is kind of recursive where the number of rows to be checked are reduced when iterating over the columns.

Interestingly, the *purrr* variant has the lowest memory requirements.

Taking the median run time of about 50 ms for the *OP2* method from this benchmark, 10000 repetitions of the simulation may take less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much Uwe.